# Ошибка при добавлении кода на сайт

Tags: javascript

Надо добавить такой код на страницу сайта:

```
$("a.gal").fancybox-content({ "frameWidth": 1500, "frameHeight": 3000 });
```

Такой код вызывает ошибку:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.gal").fancybox-content({ "frameWidth": 1500, "frameHeight": 3000 });
</script>
```

Я подозреваю, что знак `?` надо на что-то заменить.

Comment: Вы хотя бы текст ошибки указали бы в вопросе.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятнее всего что нужно подключить библиотеку [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Например, используя CDN

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Так же проверьте, подключена ли у вас библиотека, из которой вы пытаетесь вызвать **fancybox-content**

В целом порядок должен быть такой

1. Подключение jQuery
2. Подключение библиотеки
3. Ваш скрипт

Разместить лучше всего перед закрывающим тегом **body**

Comment: jquery подключена была.
Подскажите пожалуйста сам синтаксис правильный? Мне выдает ошибку **Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function**

Comment: Текст ошибки как раз говорит о том что бразуер не может найти jQuery ($ это алиас функции jQuery)

Comment: ок, спасибо. Буду хоть знать в каком направлении искать ошибку